# how to restrict apache camel to create .camel/.success folder

Tags: java, apache, apache-camel

i am using apache camel version 2.10.2. How to restrict the apache camel to create .success/.error/.camel etc. But based on certain condtion i want to create the the  respective folder also which i have explain below.

I have processor which is checking the two files in the one folder.If this two files with different extension is present then i will call different processor. But if one of the files are missing then still it creating .camel/.success folder.

i already try noop=true and in this case it is not creating folder at all.But i want the folder if the condition is true.

```
<camel:endpoint id="inputpath" uri="file:///${input.path}/INPUT/?move=.success&amp;moveFailed=.Error;recursive=true&amp;filter=#myAntFilter" />

input.path=/system/check

<camel:from ref="inputpath"  />
<camel:process ref="chkprocssr" />
<camel:choice>
    <camel:when>
        <camel:simple>${in.header.xyz} == 'YES'</camel:simple>
        <camel:process ref="aProcessor" />
    </camel:when>   
</camel:choice>
```

Expected Output ::

If two files are their in the source folder i.e  input.path=/system/check then only process the files and it should move to .success/.camel folder.If only one of the file is present in the source folder then it should remain their and shouldn't move to .success/.camel folder.
We should wait until the two files having same name with different extension come to source folder.

Comment: Setting `move=.success` means that any file which is successfully processed will be moved to the .success folder. If you only want to process the files if both are present then it suggests to me that there's something wrong with your filter. Setting `noop=true` means that the files will not be moved or deleted after having been successfully processed and that does not seem to be what you want.

Comment: @noMad17 if two files are present suppose one having .txt extension and another is .xlsx. If any one of the files is not present i don't want to process the files.I am using Processor having ref chkprocssr to check if two files are their i.e in source folder or not i.e input.path=/system/check.If it is their then in processor i am  setting in the header exchange.getIn().setHeader("xyz","YES"); If any one of the files are missing i want the file to stay their in root folder instead move to .success or .camel folder

Comment: It's important to note that once the filter has returned true (i.e. the currently processed file matches the filter) the file will be moved to either .success or .Error. You could try stopping the exchange from within the Processor using `exchange.setProperty(Exchange.ROUTE_STOP, Boolean.TRUE);` and see if that helps rather than letting the route continue.

Comment: @noMad17 i have added in processor and check still it .success folder is getting created if i put  one file.

Comment: I feared that it wouldn't work but it was worth a shot. Since this is a bit of a special scenario you might have to resort to checking if both files are present prior to actually fetching them. Perhaps you could create a route which creates a temporary file in the same directory to indicate whether both files are present. You could then use the filter in your actual route to check for that file and then delete it.

Comment: See the doneFile option

Comment: @ClausIbsen i have used doneFile like <camel:endpoint id="inputpath" uri="file:///${input.path}/INPUT/?doneFileName=${file:name}.done;move=.success&amp;moveFailed=.Error;recursive=true&amp;filter=#myAntFilter" /> but in this case the files is not processing at all .what is the issue i am not able to figure it out